# iPhone Horizontal Scrolling Table

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I need to create a view on the iPhone that scrolls horizontally through a gallery of images.  The issue is that this gallery has the potential to have 100s to 1000s of images that needs to be presented, so I would like to avoid loading them all into a single UIScrollView at once and destroying performance.  I need to create a view that recycles the view objects (like UITableView) to increase performance and reduce memory overhead, but it needs to scroll in a horizontal fashion.

Any ideas?  Is it possible to make UITableView operation horizontally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a large scrollview, and monitor for the scroll position to change.  You can add images as subviews as they are coming into the actual viewable area, and remove them as they are scrolled away.

This way, you only have to have a small number of image views present at any given time, but you give the appearance of them all being "there".

You could even recycle the image views by changing their image and location so you are not creating and destroying complex objects.  This is what UITableView does with cells.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  I was hoping there would be a way to use a recycling mechanism in the OS, and not have to manage all that in my own code...but I will make some attempts with that and see how it performs.

Comment: There is a way of using a UITableViewController, please review my answer below

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as appyling a Transform.

Here is the code. Write this in the your tableViewController init:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(100,-5,250,350); //any Frame of your choice
CGAffineTransform trans = self.view.transform; // get current transform (i.e. portrait)
trans = CGAffineTransformRotate(trans, (M_PI / -2.0)); // rotate 90 degrees to go landscape
self.view.transform = trans; // set current transform (landscape)
```

But now what you need to realize is that your axis are also swapped. Any changes you make to the height will change the width (and vice versa) and any changes made to the origin.x changes the origin.y (and vice versa)

Comment: You want "eg" not "ie" -- From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_abbreviations): "eg" is "exempli gratia" ("for example", "for instance") ; "ie" is "id est" ("that is", "in other words")

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **mbmcavoy**, you can also take a look [iPhone/iPad – AppStore like UIScrollView with paging and preview](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-ipad-appstore-like-uiscrollview-with-paging-and-preview/) this article explains what you need about UIScrollView as well as provides a good example and source code.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to add a UITableView horizontally? In a different orientation than the screen. Then you can use regular UITableView semantics where each row is an image that scrolls horizontally instead of vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer to this old thread because the validated answer is not correct. You may use a UITableViewController and its dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier built-in features.

The trick is to make your tableview rotate and then make your cell rotate in the opposite direction.

in viewDidLoad you will add:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
```

And then in cellForRowAtIndexPath you would use:

```
cell.containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

Make sure that every content of your cell is added to a container view (in this example *containerView*) so that you only have to rotate the container and not every cell subview.

Also please note that it will work better with cells having square dimensions, cause otherwise you may struggle with height/width computation.

Answer (score -1):

I think I have the answer for you About scrolling an `UITableView` Horizontally:

1. create an `UIScrollView` (and disable
   the vertical scroll)
2. put an `UITableView` inside the scroll
   view
3. change the table view width as you
   wish and update the
   `UIScrollView.contentSize` as the
   tableView width

Comment: Adding a table view does not make it scroll horizontally regardless of width.